# Postgresql / INSERT performance fall when doing a single SELECT during a batch of INSERTs

Tags: postgresql, insert, database-performance

**Context:**

Using PostgreSQL (9.6), for a custom synchronisation project, we have an agent that make a lot of `INSERTs` between a database_1 and database_2 when syncing data.

***For example***: DB2 is down during 5 minutes, there are 40,000 new lines in DB1, so when DB2 is up again, all the 40,000 lines will be immediately synced from DB1 to DB2.

All this works great.

**Problem/Fact**:

During the synchronisation, the `INSERT` rate is around 1000 lines / second.

However, when we do a simple `SELECT count(*) FROM table` during the sync (in the middle of these thousands of INSERTs), we noticed that the INSERT rate is falling town to a **few dozens per second** (instead of 1000x per second).

**Question:**

Is there any reason why a `SELECT` operation (made inside pgAdmin, by another process than the syncing process) is slowing down the batch of `INSERT` ?

- Any locking or internal reason that might explain this?
- Or should I provide more information? How can I debug more?

---

Hints:

- Logs are fully activated and all the `INSERTs` always take around 0.700ms (before slowdown and same during slowdown), it doesn't change.
- INSERTs are currently performed one row by one row
- *(I'll be happy to provide more information)*

Comment: The `SELECT` will write [*hint bits*](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Hint_Bits) if it's the first read of the data. But that doesn't explain that kind of write performance drop unless the storage system is utterly pathetic at concurrent I/O. Usually readers don't get in the way of writers or vice versa.

Comment: The server is quite powerful and storage is SSD, and rows are around ~100 bytes --     Is there anything I can do to provide more debugging data?  Actually I even don't know "how" can I debug this further ...

Comment: a couple of questions: are the inserts being performed in bulk or 1 row at a time? does the insert process have autocommit turned on or, if not, is it making commits after each insert query, or after the batch of insert queries?

Comment: Inserts are being performed one by one (the bulk or COPY is not easily possible in the sync prototype we're building)      _(I'll check asap about autocommit)_

Comment: Analysing this sort of thing tends to involve considerable data collection with `perf` etc. Look into https://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_support/ . (Disclaimer, I work for one of the listed companies).

Comment: @HaleemurAli - About autocommit : yes currently activated.

Comment: @CraigRinger I'll definitely look at that. I was not aware that that kind of companies could also offer "short-term debugging", I thought it was only for bigger and long term projects. Thanks.

Comment: you might get some speed increase if you turn off autocommit for each insert & instead commit after a batch of inserts. But, in this setting, the uncommitted rows will not show up in the `select count(*) from table` query. I don't know if that's an acceptable compromise in your application.

Comment: I'll check this and try to provide additional information and feedbacks. Thanks a lot!